# Why is DirectShow dragging in unnecessary intermediate filters when making multiple input connections to my DirectShow Transform filter?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, dspack

I have a DirectShow Transform filter written in Delphi 6 using the DSPACK component library.  It is a simple audio mixer that creates a new input pin whenever a new connection is attempted.  I say simple because once its media format is set, all connections to the its input pins or singular output pin are forced to conform to that media format.  I build the filter chain manually, making all pin connections explicitly myself.  I do not use any of the "intelligent rendering" calls, unless there is some way to trigger that unwanted behavior (in my case) accidentally.

*NOTE: The Capture Filter is a standard DirectShow filter external to my application.  My push source audio filter and simple audio mixer filters are being used as private, unregistered filters and are internal to my application.*

I am having a weird problem that only occurs when I try to make multiple input connections to my mixer, which does indeed accept them.  Currently, I am attempting to connect both a Capture Filter and my custom Push Source audio filter to my mixer filter.  Whenever I try to do that the second upstream filter connection fails. Regardless of whether I connect the Capture Filter first or Push Source audio filter first, the second upstream filter connection always fails.

The first test I ran was to try connecting just the Capture Filter to the mixer.  That worked fine.

The second test I ran was to try connecting just the Push Source audio filter to the mixer.  That worked fine.

But as soon as try to do both I get a "no combination of intermediate filters could be found" error.  I did several hours of deep digging into the media negotiation calls hitting my filter from the graph builder and then I found the problem.  For some reason, the filter graph is dragging in the ancient "**Indeo (R) Audio Software**" codec into the chain.

I discovered this because despite the fact that codec did have a media format that matched my filter in **almost** every regard (major type, sub type, format type, wave format parameters), it had an extra 2 bytes at the end of it's pbFormat data member and that was enough to fail the **equals** test since that test does a comparison between the source and target pbFormat areas by comparing the cbFormat value of each media type.  The Indeo codec has a cbFormat value of 20 while my filter has a cbFormat value of 18, which is the size of a _tWAVEFORMATEX data structure.  In a way it's a good thing the Indeo pbFormat has that weird size because the first 18 bytes of its 20 byte area were exactly equal to the pbFormat area of my mixer filter's supported media type.  Without that anomaly I never would have known that ancient codec was being drug in.  I'm surprised it's being drug in at all since it has known exploits and vulnerabilities.  What is most confusing is that this is happening on my mixer filter's **output** pin, not one of the input pins, and **I have not made a single downstream connection yet** when building up my pin connections.

Can anyone tell me why DirectShow is trying to drag in that codec despite the fact that the media formats for the both incoming filters, the Capture Filter and the Push Source filter, are identical and don't need any intermediate filters at all since they match my mixer filter's input pins supported format exactly?  How can I fix this problem?

Also, I noticed that even in the single filter attachment tests above that succeeded, my mixer output pin was still getting queried for media formats.  Why is that when as I said, at this point in building up my pin connections I have not connected anything to the output pin of my mixer filter?

--------------------------- UPDATE: 1 ----------------------------

I have learned that you can avoid the "intelligent connection" behavior entirely by using IFilterGraph.ConnectDirect() instead of IGraphBuilder.Connect().  I switched over to DirectConnect() and turns out that the input pin on my mixer filter is coming back as "already connected".  That may be what is causing the graph builder to drag in the Indeo codec filter.  Now that I have this new diagnostic information I will correct the problem and update this post with my results.

Comment: Unnecessary filters are dragged due to one of the two reasons: (1) bad media type exposed on a filter to be connected, or fitler's failure to accept well-defined media type, and (2) bad/broken filter registration such as with unexpectedly high merit. All the issues with the mentiuned symptoms are along these lines.

Comment: Good to know @Roman R.  Have you ever found a tool, technique, or testing method to unearth and track down those kinds of failures as quickly as possible?

Comment: `GraphStudio` and `DirectShowSpy` - these are my tools. Of course, it also takes an alert eye to notice problems in inspected media types.

Comment: GraphStudioNext ( https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/) also allows selecting a media type to connect with as well as connecting directly and intelligent connect.

Answer (score 0):

**--------------------------- RESOLUTION ----------------------------**

The root problem of all of this was my re-use of the input pin I obtained from the first destination/downstream filter I connected to my simple audio mixer filter, at the top of my application code.  In other words my filter was working correctly, but I was not getting a fresh input pin with each upstream filter I tried to connect to it.  Once I started doing that the connection process worked fine.  I don't know why the code behind the IGraphBuilder.Connect() interface tried to bring in the Indeo codec filter, perhaps something to do with trying to connect to an already connected input pin, but it did.  For my needs, I prefer the tight control that IFilterGraph.ConnectDirect() provides since it eliminates any interference from the intelligent connection code in IGraphBuilder, but I could see when video filters get involved it could become useful.